# c malloc error code :3096

Tags: c, malloc

Hello friends i'm having a problem using malloc the error code is 3096:

> malloc.c:3096: sYSMALLOc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long)old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.
>   Abort

Code:

```
    char    *malloc_tab(char *str)
    {
      if ((str = malloc(1024)) == NULL)
        return (NULL);
      return (str);
    }

    int     *malloc_tab_int(int *str)
    {
      int   i;

      i = 0;
      if ((str = malloc(1024)) == NULL)
        return (NULL);
      while (i != 1024)
        {
          str[i] = 0;
          i = i + 1;
        }
      return (str);
    }

char    **malloc_dim_tab(char **str)
{
  int   y;

  y = 0;
  if ((str = malloc(1024 * sizeof(*str))) == NULL)
    return (NULL);
  while (y < 200)
    {
      if ((str[y] = malloc(1024 * sizeof(**str))) == NULL)
        return (NULL);
      y = y + 1;
    }
  return (str);
}
```

any help pls!

Comment: 3096 isn't the error code, it's the source code line number of the assertion that failed. When you see something of the form foobar.c:1234, that generally means line 1234 of foobar.c.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one mistake within the `malloc_tab_int()` function:

```
if ((str = malloc(1024)) == NULL)
```

as it is allocating 1024 bytes only, not enough memory for 1024 `int`s (the `sizeof(int)` is typically 4). The subsequent `while` loop that is initializing the elements of the `str` array will be accessing beyond the memory allocated, causing [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

To correct, either:

- [`malloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) the correct number of bytes:

  ```
  if ((str = malloc(1024 * sizeof(int))) == NULL)
  /* if ((str = malloc(1024 * sizeof(*str))) == NULL) */
  ```
- or use [`calloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc) to initialize the memory and eliminate the `while` loop:

  ```
  str = calloc(1024, sizeof(int));
  /* str = calloc(1024, sizeof(*str)); */
  ```

Other:

- `str` is quite a confusing variable name for a list of `int`s.
- The argument in both `malloc_tab()` and `malloc_tab_int()` serve no purpose. In both cases, the functions can be revised to a single line `return` (and then why have these at all):

  ```
  char* malloc_tab()     { return malloc(1024);              }
  int*  malloc_tab_int() { return calloc(1024, sizeof(int)); }
  ```
- Another source of problem will be attempting to [`free()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free) the array of `char*` allocated within `malloc_dim_tab()`. Only the first 200 elements are initialized (pointing to `malloc()`d memory) but there is 1024 `char*` in the allocated memory. Calling `free()` on a value other than that returned by `malloc()`, `realloc()` or `calloc()` is undefined behaviour (which can happen in this case as 824 elements will contain random values), but calling `free()` on a `NULL` pointer is safe.

Answer (score 0):

your error code like this :"malloc.c:3096: sYSMALLOc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) "
means that due to current malloc() write/read overflow before next malloc() in your code.

you can try doing:
    str = malloc(1024 * sizeof(char *))